# error: using typedef-name after class

Tags: c++, class, typedef

I can't figure out what the actual problem is with this.

```
typedef struct _actor
{
   ...
} _actor, Actor;

class Actor
{
   ...
};
```

I get this weird error message `actor.cpp:31: error: using typedef-name ‘Actor’ after ‘class’`.

Any idea what I did wrong here? Thank you :)

Comment: BTW, the typedef-struct artifact is used only in C, where the struct names and the other types' names reside in different namespaces (not to be intended in C++ sense); in C++ struct and class names can be used "normally", so the this C-typedef idiom isn't necessary.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you're getting those â€˜ characters in the error message because you're using putty and need to set the "Received data assumed to be in which character set" option to UTF-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not allowed to define the symbol `Actor` more than once. The `typedef` statement already defines the symbol `Actor` as an alias for `struct _actor` before you attempt to declare a class with the same name.

I'm guessing you're using the `gcc` compiler. I get the following errors when I compile with `gcc`:

```
../src/main.cpp:113: error: using typedef-name ‘Actor’ after ‘class’
../src/main.cpp:111: error: ‘Actor’ has a previous declaration here
```

The first message (pointing the `class Actor` line in the program) states that you cannot declare a class with a `typedef-name` (`Actor` is already declared using `typedef`). The second message (pointing to the `typedef struct _actor` line in the program) is a little clearer and refers to the multiple declarations for `Actor`.

It is very common in C/C++ for a single class of error like this to result in multiple compiler errors and often the more helpful message is not the first reported.

Comment: could you elaborate a little? I'm still sort of new to this.

Comment: @Boco: Simply put, you are trying to create two different types with the same name.

Comment: Thank you :). Removing the , Actor at the end seems to have resolved that issue.

Comment: Still, I don't understand why you are using that typedef.

Answer (score 5):

To understand what going on, we need to break the first statement up into it's parts:

```
struct _actor 
{ 
   ... 
};

typedef struct _actor _actor;
typedef struct _actor Actor;
```

First we create a structure called `_actor`.  Next, we create a typedef for `struct _actor` called `_actor`. This is only useful in C.  It allows us to say:

```
  _actor myActor;
```

instead of

```
 struct _actor myActor;
```

But in C++, it's unnecessary, as C++ allows us to use the first form natively, without the typedef.

The third line creates a second typedef for `struct _actor` called `Actor`.
When you then try to create a class named `Actor` the compiler complains, as that name is already being used for the alias for the struct.

Now, it seems likely that in the original C code, the author had intended `struct _actor` to be merely an implementation detail, and that you would always use just `Actor` to refer to instances of this struct.  Therefore, in your C++ code, you should probably eliminate the typedefs entirely, and just rename the struct.   However, that will give you:

```
 struct Actor {.....}
 class  Actor {.....}
```

So, prehaps you should look into merging those two classes.

Answer (score 0):

for arduino hectop 3d printer:

Rename `fpos_t` variables in `SdBaseFile.h` and `SdBaseFile.cpp` to another name like `fpos_t1` and recompile.